# FindWindow() fails, but GetLastError returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi

Recently, I decided to improve the error processing in a little app I had made; to test my functions, I tried introducing a basic error by giving a false window name to `FindWindow`. The error was successfully caught, but my error function told me the last error, given by `GetLastError`, was 0.

I tried introducing errors in other parts of the program, all of which were caught, and gave some sort of actual error code. When a real window name was passed to `FindWindow`, the function worked flawlessly.

I created an isolated test to see if something else in my program was causing problems, which you can see here;

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    wstring wstr = L"asdasdasd";

    wcout << wstr << endl;

    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, wstr.c_str());

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        cout << "Window not found" << endl;
    }

    cout << GetLastError();

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, there is no window in existence called "asdasdasd". And the test confirms so, running the code gives:

```
asdasdasd           //wstring created correctly
Window not found    //Output of FindWindow() is NULL
0                   //GetLastError() is 0
```

(Comments added post-test)

The windows API documentation for [`FindWindowA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) reads:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the window that has the specified class name and window name.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

So shouldn't I be getting an error code back from `GetLastError`? Is there an edge case I'm hitting where this doesn't occur?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220188/discussion-on-question-by-the4naves-findwindow-fails-but-getlasterror-returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus from the comments seems to be that `FindWindow` simply doesn't set an error if no window is found (Though other errors do, which I tested). Personally, this seems like pretty misleading documentation, especially as other function in the windows api will set an error code if they fail to do their job, even if no actual errors occur, but I digress.

Comment: The function is called `FindWindow`. Not finding a window is a **successful** outcome. Why do you expect the API call to set the thread's last error code (which you aren't properly evaluating anyway)?

Comment: If you find the documentation to be misleading [suggest an edit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa.md).

Comment: @IInspectable Because in the Return section of the documentation, it clearly states that it will return a handle to a window on success, and NULL on failure, and that on failure you can call ```GetLastError``` to get extended info. I would expect more information on a failure to tell me, well, exactly that, not that the function succeeded.

Comment: @IInspectable I understand your logic, I just think the docs give the idea that if the function returns NULL, you can expect ```GetLastError``` to give you more info, which would generally mean an error code other than 0. Thank you for the link however, I'll consider making a request, though to be honest, I don't really see it being approved.

Comment: @IInspectable Or to be accurate, ```FindWindow``` doesn't even set an error if there isn't a window with the specified info.

Comment: `GetLastError` **does** give more information. If it returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`, it means, that you didn't find a window given your predicate, and this is **not** the result of an error internal to the API trying to find an answer. As for proposing requests to change the API documentation, my experience was that **none** were rejected to this day.

Comment: @IInspectable Like I said, it doesn't set an error at all, allowing previous errors to propagate through. I agree now that in the example I gave, the given error did give more info, but it doesn't always, which I think the documentation should specify. I'll make a pull request for that extra info. The reason I'm unsure, is that I don't think functions usually specify when they don't set an error.

Comment: Are you saying that if you call `SetLastError(42);` prior to calling `FindWindow` (for a predicate that doesn't find a window), the return value is `NULL` and `GetLastError` still returns 42? If that is the case, then you should not just propose a documentation change, but also file a defect report. I don't know how to file an API defect report in this day and age, though.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I tested to make sure, any previous errors will propagate though. However I read the docs for ```GetLastError```, which states;  "**Most** functions... ...set it when they fail... ...If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set". So it seems like this is simply how the windows api works.

Comment: @IInspectable Unfortunately, it seems like there a ton of other function with similar return statements, many of which probably also don't set the error code on that kind of failure. Assuming that's the case, it would probably take too much effort to change for such a small problem.

Comment: Seems like the solution is to call `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);` before calling it then.

Comment: @JonathanPotter True, although it'd be nicer if the function just set the error code on failure automatically, though I'm sure there's some obscure reason that isn't done.